# Trouble showing high-maps and high-charts on same page?

Tags: charts, highcharts

```js
    // Initiate the chart
    $('#container_origin').highcharts('Map', {
  
  
        title : {
            text : 'Heat Map Of Visited Orgins'
        },

        subtitle : {
            text : ''
        },
  

        mapNavigation: {
            enabled: true,
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom'
            }
        },

   colorAxis: {
                min: 1,
                type: 'logarithmic',
                minColor: '#338ACA',
                maxColor: '#1B4761'
            },
   
   

        series : [{
  
  
            data : data,
            mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world-highres'],
            joinBy: 'hc-key',
            //name: 'Random data',
            states: {
                hover: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[6]
                }
            },
   
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                format: '{point.name}'
            },
   tooltip: {
                headerFormat: '',
            }
   
   
   
        }]
    });
```

```html
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  
  <!--Use this for maps/chart combo -->
  <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
  
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="chart.css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="bb.js"></script>

  
 </head>
```

I'm having trouble rendering highcharts and highmaps on the same page. At first, I was just getting an error but then I swapped.

```
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-highres.js"></script>
```

With this -

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
```

I now get the out line of the chart (see img). Can anybody suggest a solution? [image]

Comment: see this http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/getting-started   and this http://forum.highcharts.com/highmaps-usage-f14/highmaps-with-highcharts-4-t29253/

Comment: I did that and its brought me to this stage.

Comment: works fine on its own single page with the normal links. fyi

Comment: What kind of error? Could you post a live example, like jsFiddle?

Answer (score 6):

As you can see from [this getting started tutorial / Highmaps documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/getting-started) for Highmaps to work you need to load, [same as in Highcharts and Highstock](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/installation), a framework - jQuery or Standalone Highcharts Framework and:

1) highmaps.js

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
```

or, if you have a license for Highcharts and Highmaps, 2) highcharts.js + maps.js module

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/pe40p00y/14/

Comment: Great answer. You beat me to it.

Comment: I've updated the jsfiddle with your head and it's still running: http://jsfiddle.net/pe40p00y/16/

Comment: Can you not show your code in a jsfiddle? If you can't show your data, just add something random in your series.

Comment: There allot of it and allot going on to put in a fiddle. It works fine on its own page using the normal headers. Its went I put it in combination with normal charts.

Comment: If i use this -  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/highmaps.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/exporting.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world-highres.js"></script> on its own it works

Comment: @user5554551 Use `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>` (as [**Ryan**'s example](http://jsfiddle.net/pe40p00y/14/) shows) when creating Highcharts and Highmaps on same page - this combination will work when creating one or both types.

Comment: Still the same result.... It like the map is no being created. Iv added soem code above

Comment: @user5554551 Do you have any errors in browser console (Developer Tools) ? Can you recreate the issue on live example? Are you loading all required files (like used map(s)) and data is correct?

Comment: As I have said before. No real errors. Part of the high-map displays as show above, but the actual map doesn't. It works fine on its own page its just when I try to combine chart and map. I do get this in the console tho.'webkitMovementX' is deprecated. Please use 'movementX' instead. ---- in highcharts.js

Comment: @user5554551 Map is not loaded - custom/world-highres is not loaded. If you are using https, then load all files through https. Do not load same files more than once. Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rbfgh0cm/

Answer (score 1):

I have Pie, Column and Stock Charts and big trouble to integrate Map with it. I found out that these lines fix this problem:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/world.js"></script>
```

This is result I got.

[image: Map Chart]

You have to link map as a **module**.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use Highmaps and map module together. You can use the map modlue as a plugin with Highcharts:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/maps/modules/map.js"></script>
```

**Docs** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/getting-started